# android programming listview by xml can not start

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, listview

What is wrong with this program?

I want that when I click at the Button, it goes to List View? Just by writing xml code, not layout.

http://s5.picofile.com/file/8132938634/Main.PNG  "Main"

http://s5.picofile.com/file/8132938784/Menu.PNG  "Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Main  at

```
startActivity(new Intent(Min.this,Menu.class)) ;
```

replace it by

```
startActivity(new Intent(Min.this,com.example.acxxas.Menu.class)) ;
```

For next time please avoid naming your activity as predefine classess.

there Menu refers to `android.view.Menu.class;`

Answer (score 2):

you need to write the menu activity in the android manifest, have you done it? after you will do it it will turn to the "menu.java" file:

add this line to the manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.yourpackage.menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   try{
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClassName(Menu.this,getPackageName()+"."+classes[position]);
       startActivity(intent);
   }catch (Throwable e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```